# Calling custom functions within Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

So, I have a dirt simple tooltip written in jQuery,
it only requires an element to have class="tooltips" and a  right after the element
(and the css ofcourse)

But how do I implement it on a polyline in Google Maps?

```
function tooltipDisplay() {
    return function() { $(this).contents("span:last-child").css({ display: "block" }); }
}
function tooltipHide() {
    return function() { $(this).contents("span:last-child").css({ display: "none" }); }
}
function tooltipMove() {
    return function(e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 10;
        var mousey = e.pageY + 5;
        $(this).contents("span:last-child").css({  top: mousey, left: mousex });
    }
}
$(".tooltips").hover(tooltipDisplay(),tooltipHide());

    $(".tooltips").mousemove(tooltipMove());
```

I tried using

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'mouseover', tooltipDisplay());

    google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'mouseout', tooltipHide());

    google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'mousemove', tooltipMove());
```

without any results. (obviously because I can't make a span on a polyline for starters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right. SOLVED.

After a bit of jumping through hoops and whatnot it turned out to be easier than it seemed.

Simply put: "this" isn't useful with Google Maps Polylines, as it's the document. As such I took it down a notch and gave it it's own simple functions as such:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'mouseover', function() {
        $('#mapTooltip').show();
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'mouseout', function() {
        $('#mapTooltip').hide();
    });
```

However I also noticed the act of placing the tooltip couldn't be done with a mouseover in the Listener as it had to call an element anyways which resulted in a loop where it was firing whenever I moved anywhere, as such, in the document.ready area I added this:

```
function tooltipMove(e) {
    var y = e.pageY;
    var x = e.pageX;

    $("span").css({
        top:y+5,
        left:x+10
    });
}

$("#gMap").mousemove(tooltipMove);
```

And then just styled the css to fit.
Simple as that!

Answer (score 1):

Not related directly to the question (so making this Wiki as well), but there's no need for all those function wrappers, just use `tooltipDisplay` instead of `tooltipDisplay()` when calling...use the function directly, not the result of invoking it, like this overall:

```
function tooltipDisplay() {
    $(this).contents("span:last-child").css({ display: "block" });
}
function tooltipHide() {
    $(this).contents("span:last-child").css({ display: "none" });
}
function tooltipMove(e) {
    var mousex = e.pageX + 10;
    var mousey = e.pageY + 5;
    $(this).contents("span:last-child").css({  top: mousey, left: mousex });
}
$(".tooltips").hover(tooltipDisplay,tooltipHide).mousemove(tooltipMove);
```

Comment: Unrelated but appreciated. :) (Leaving my post unedited for future comparison)

Comment: And I know it's still unrelated but could you quickly explain the differences between the two and the advantages of your changes?

Comment: @Meke - basically you're eliminating a layer from each, when you call with `()` you're executing the function with no parameters *right then*, not when the event runs...so you have to return a function that *does* run at the time of the event...there's basically no need for this in many cases (unless you need a specific closure, etc).  If you just remove the extra layer, you're defining that function that runs *at the time of the event* and using it directly when assigning your event handlers.